# Nuxt.js: Problem with css-loader which strips quotes from font-family

Tags: javascript, webpack, quotes, nuxt.js, css-loader

I have the following problem: I built a nuxt.js vue app, which uses a google font.

I load it in the head (by adding the url to the head section of my nuxt.config.js) `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,400i,700`

I then use a sass-variable:
`$s-font-family-base: 'Playfair Display', serif;`
Which I use throughout my stylings to display this font.

Now when I check my browsers inspector while running a dev server, everything looks alright:

[image]

But if I use `yarn generate` (`nuxt generate` respectively) this will result in a font-family property with stripped quotes. Also if I push production to live.

[image]

Of course this is not nice, leads to invalid CSS, and maybe results in font loading failure...

Now I assume this is linked to nuxts css-loader:
https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader

But I am not fully sure if I should open an issue there.
(I started to create a minimal nuxt repo to reproduce, but then I experienced a bug within the getting started guide: https://cmty.app/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/c9213)

Anyway, in the meantime I just wanted to reach out for some pointers on this topic.
Cheers and thanks for any help.

Comment: i have commented on your create nuxt issue

Answer (score 3):

This solved me.

cssnano option
https://cssnano.co/optimisations/minifyfontvalues/

before

```
.box {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

after

```
.box {
    font-family: Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

your nuxt.config

```
  build: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: {
        cssnano: {
          preset: ['default', {minifyFontValues: {removeQuotes: false}}]
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: Awesome. I will try. Thanks